# How do i click in a div class using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, bots, puppeteer

I'm trying to click in a button but i only have the class
[name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whoqV.png), i'm trying to use page.click, but never work so i try to add waitForSelector and always gives me [time out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBdjr.png), my code is very poor i'm just trying to learn more about to create new projects.

[this is the item i'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNIxz.png)

[Also can be this item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GGOD.png)

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    product : "chrome",
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width:1920,
    height:1080
  })

  try{
    await page.goto('https://br.betano.com/login/')
  await delay(1000)
  await page.keyboard.type('*******')
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
  await page.keyboard.type('******')
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
  await delay(5000)
  await page.goto('https://br.betano.com/casino/live/games/roleta-brasileira/444/tables/103910/')
  await delay(2000)
  await page.keyboard.press('Escape')
  await delay(10000)
  await page.waitForSelector('[class="header__more-games"]')
 await page.click('[class="header__more-games"]')

  }catch(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
  
 })();
```

Comment: I can't access the site because I'm in the US. But you can make a [mcve] of it and use `page.setContent` to reproduce the behavior (although if you can do this, it probably answers your question). If the element is invisible, make sure it's not in a iframe for starters. BTW, instead of `'[class="header__more-games"]'` just do `.header__more-games`.

Comment: i think the element is invisible, because i only can find in "Console" if i found the item in "elements" first

Comment: That's almost certainly a frame issue.

Comment: ow i understant, i know it's possible get the values of the next page because here in Brazil a lot of peoples has a bot for this Website, i just need to figure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the selector to select a particular element and click on it or you can also use Xpath.

Here is how you can get the Selector

1. Right-click on the Element in Browser Devtools.
2. Select Copy, then Copy Selector

[image]

Now, Replace these lines with the below one.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('[class="header__more-games"]')
await page.click('[class="header__more-games"]')
```

Make sure to replace the `Your Selector Here` with the actual selector you copied in the above steps.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('Your Selector Here');
const buttonClick = await page.$("Your Selector Here");
   
await buttonClick.click();
```

Comment: hello, thanks for you answer i try to do what you tell me, but i got a error: (TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null)

Comment: Well, I just edited the code. You need `waitForSelector`

Comment: i'm still geting TimeOut i think the website is the problem but i figure how to do using iFrame link, thanks for your time man. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I figure how to do it by using link in an `iframe`, in my case the link is always the same, so I just get the link and open in another tap. Like this:

```js
await page2.goto('https://cachedownload-br.p-content.gambling-malta.com/live/?tableId=103910&game=rol&preferedmode=real&language=pt-br&advertiser=ptt/&clienttype=casino')
await page2.bringToFront()
await delay(15000)
const [button] = await page2.$x("//button[contains(., 'Ok')]");
if (button) {
  await button.click();
}
```